# Is there a known FPRAS for this simple partition function?

Tags: counting, applied-theory

I Let $G$ be the set of simple graphs on $n$ nodes. Given a $g \in G$, we denote the number of triangles in $g$ with $n(g)$. Given some positive real-valued parameter $w$, we define the the function $Z(w)$ as follows:
$$Z(w)= \sum_{g}\exp(w\cdot n(g))$$

I think its an intractable problem to compute $Z(w)$, but I don't know about approximations. Is there a known FPRAS for computing $Z(w)$?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Partition function is a bad name here inspired from physics/statistics/Machine Learning. But it does not matter, I have edited the question to just have it as $Z(w)$. But if you are interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)

Comment: I assume that $G$ is the set of *all* simple *undirected* graphs on $n$ nodes. I didn't find the solution, but maybe the following will help. It suffices to know the distribution of the number of triangles in an Erdos-Renyi graph with $p= \frac 12$. Basically, something like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338267/distribution-and-variance-of-count-of-triangles-in-random-graph, but you need to know the whole distribution.

Comment: So, basically, you are interested in [Moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) for the number of triangles in Erdos-Renyi$(n, \frac 12)$.